# LazyColumn animateItemPlacement doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I have a problem, animateItemPlacement in my LazyColumn simply doesn't work, code:

```
val laps = stopWatchViewModel.getLapsStates().collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(start = 52.dp, end = 52.dp)
) {
    items(items = laps.value, key = {lap -> lap.id}) { lap ->
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top = 12.dp, bottom = 12.dp)
                .animateItemPlacement(
                    animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 250)
                ),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text(text = lap.lap, color = Color(0xff383838), fontSize = 20.sp)
            Text(text = lap.lapTime, color = Color(0xff808080), fontSize = 20.sp)
            Text(text = lap.totalTime, color = Color(0xfff7f7f7), fontSize = 20.sp)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use key = { it }(it gives an exception), tried to use key = { it.id }, tried to use key = {lap -> lap.id}. It simply doesn't want to work, but keys are unic. Also i tried to change container to the box or card. This is project on git: (https://github.com/BRBXGIT/AlarmApp). Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean by "it doesn't work" that the items just appear abruptly when you add new items?

Comment: What happens when you just use the vanilla ```.animateItemPlacement()```?

Comment: @BenjyTec yes, i mean that, they just appear abruptly

Comment: @tomerpacific nothing happens, they just appear abruptly, without any animation

Comment: @ЕгорСауткин - What happens if you change the container of your item from row to something else? I.E. Card?

Comment: @tomerpacific yes i tried to use card and box, but it did not work

Comment: Did you also try to wrap your `Row` into a `Box` and add the `animateItemPlacement` Modifier to the `Box`?

Comment: @BenjyTec yes i tried it, and also i tried to wrap my row into the card, it didn't work

Comment: I was suggesting it because this problem is also mentioned here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/312294403

Comment: @BenjyTec i have already saw it, and did not find solution there

Comment: @BenjyTec i add link to project on git, if you want, you can can copy and try it on your computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i understand how to do this animation. The trick is that now animation of inserting or deleting something from LazyColumn is unavailable. Because if you add something to list, ui is need to be recomposed, and it doesn't support animation yet. To solve this problem, i created custom animation with Modifier.graphicsLayer. Code:

```
val laps = stopWatchViewModel.getLapsStates().collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(start = 52.dp, end = 52.dp)
) {
    items(items = laps.value) {lap ->
        var lapVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        val animatedLapAlpha by animateFloatAsState(
            targetValue = if (lapVisible) 1f else 0f,
            label = "Lap alpha",
            animationSpec = tween(
                durationMillis = 250,
                easing = LinearEasing,
            )
        )
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp)
                .graphicsLayer {
                    lapVisible = true
                    alpha = animatedLapAlpha
                },
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text(text = lap.lap, color = Color(0xff383838), fontSize = 20.sp)
            Text(text = lap.lapTime, color = Color(0xff808080), fontSize = 20.sp)
            Text(text = lap.totalTime, color = Color(0xfff7f7f7), fontSize = 20.sp)
        }
    }
}
```

P.s. Later such animations will be
available with `animateItemPlacement()`, but not now